# Offset, named range and data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

`=VERSCHUIVING($AJ$9;0;0;$AJ$17;1)` or `Offset($AJ$9,0,0,$AJ$17,1)`in english

With AJ9 being the start of a vertical list of options, and AJ17 being the length of that list.

I use this in a named range and use it for data validation using the `Indirect` fucntion. When I want to select an argument from the list of this named range nothing appears, and when entering the Indirect formula it says it evaluates to an error. I tried entering the formula as an array formula using `cmd + shift + enter`and it only displayed the value of Cell AJ9 instead of expanding downwards to an array.

Any suggestions to make this work (on excel for mac)

EDIT:

Just tried on a windows version, also no succes. When I open the name manager and enter the formula there it does show the dotted lines around the correct selection. However when I turn on data validation it still evaluates to an error.

EDIT2:

If I enter `=CriticalPractice`(the name of my named range) in a cell it highlights cells AJ9 and AJ17. When I press enter I get `#VALUE!`. If I enter it as an array formula I get the value of cell AJ9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of **dynamically-defined** Names and `INDIRECT` is not permitted within Data Validation. In such cases you need to employ `EVALUATE`, though you should note that, despite no explicit VBA being called, this will nevertheless require that the workbook be saved as macro-enabled.

For example, assuming cell `AL7` contains the text, e.g. "Name1", which is to be interpreted as the Defined Name, i.e. *Name1* (whose definition is the `OFFSET` construction you give), then the following additional definition would be made in Name Manager:

*Name:* `Name2`
*Refers to:* `=EVALUATE($AL$7)`

After which the Data Validation list can be obtained via using the *List* option and entering:

`=Name2`

in the *Source* box.

Regards

Comment: Using evaluate is not going to work for me as I can't use a xlsm file. I think my best bet would be to hard code a named range for each of the possible range lenghts, luckily there are only 4 options. Would you also  happen to know why this combination is not permitted, as it is an excelent way to remove unnecessary blanks from a list?

Comment: Then yes, with so few options for the range lengths, I would proceed as you suggest. I'm afraid I'm not sure why that combination is not permitted within Data Validation. Hopefully someone will pick up on this thread who can shed some light on the matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954283/why-data-validation-cant-handle-dynamic-named-ranges-through-indirect