# Why data validation can't handle dynamic named ranges through Indirect

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had a problem with creating dynamic named ranges and incorporating that with data validation. On my previous question this was the (part of) the answer given by XOR LX: [offset, named range and data validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947589/offset-named-range-and-data-validation)

> The combination of dynamically-defined Names and `INDIRECT` is not
>   permitted within Data Validation. In such cases you need to employ
>   `EVALUATE`, though you should note that, despite no explicit VBA being
>   called, this will nevertheless require that the workbook be saved as
>   macro-enabled.

Question remains why data validation can't handle this?

In my case I decided to hard code all possible options, as they were limited in number, but are there other options without making use of VBA?